# How to Replace the env name from the domain name that is reading the from the CSV file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am reading the domain url from the CSVdatafile before hitting I need to replace the environment with some String
How I can achieve in Jmeter
data file entries
Tried following by adding the BeanShellPreprocesser

```java
print("------Replcing the environment name------");
var str =new Stirng[]{${siteUrl}};
var res = str.replace("frep", ${env});
SampleResult.setResponseData(res);
```

still it is not working.
I need to read each entry from the Datafile and replace the "frep" with "abc" and then i need to hit the url

How I can achieve this in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario Beanshell code should look like:

```
String siteUrl = vars.get("siteUrl");
siteUrl = siteUrl.replaceAll("frep", vars.get("env"));
vars.put("siteUrl", siteUrl);
```

Beanshell is more like Java, not JavaScript. You can use [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function to perform the substitution if you're more comfortable with it.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more detailed explanation of Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Also be aware that